# Progress 4GL GET request on open.mapquestapi.com

Tags: rest, sockets, geolocation, openedge, progress-4gl

I have a serious problem with proper GET method calling on [open.mapquestapi.com](http://open.mapquestapi.com) to get some geolocation data.
My code is quite standard, mostly taken from Progress KB and other sites.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE vcHost   AS CHARACTER INITIAL "open.mapquestapi.com" NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE vcPort   AS CHARACTER INITIAL "80" NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE vhSocket AS HANDLE    NO-UNDO.

CREATE SOCKET vhSocket.
vhSocket:CONNECT('-H ' + vcHost + ' -S 80')NO-ERROR.

IF vhSocket:CONNECTED() = FALSE THEN
DO:
    MESSAGE "Connection failure" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

    MESSAGE ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(1) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    RETURN.
END.
ELSE
    MESSAGE "Connect"
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

This part of code returns message "Connect" so I believe I'm properly connected.
Next part:

```
vhSocket:SET-READ-RESPONSE-PROCEDURE('getResponse').
RUN GetRequest.

WAIT-FOR READ-RESPONSE OF vhSocket.
vhSocket:DISCONNECT() NO-ERROR.
DELETE OBJECT vhSocket.
QUIT.

PROCEDURE GetRequest:
    DEFINE VARIABLE vcRequest AS CHARACTER.
    DEFINE VARIABLE mRequest  AS MEMPTR.

vcRequest = 'GET ' +
    '/nominatim/v1' +
    '/search.php?key=WLrMQcGao56Cb5m4ulmwZZDOegO3BkZn&format=xml&q=warszawa chałubińskiego 8&addressdetails=1&limit=50' +
    " ~r~n HTTP/1.1 ~r~n" +
    "~r~nConnection: close~r~n~r~n".

    MESSAGE vcREquest
        VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

    SET-SIZE(mRequest)            = 0.
    SET-SIZE(mRequest)            = LENGTH(vcRequest) + 1.
    SET-BYTE-ORDER(mRequest)      = BIG-ENDIAN.
    PUT-STRING(mRequest,1)        = vcRequest .

    vhSocket:WRITE(mRequest, 1, LENGTH(vcRequest)).
END PROCEDURE.

PROCEDURE getResponse:
    DEFINE VARIABLE vcWebResp AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE lSucess   AS LOGICAL   NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE mResponse AS MEMPTR    NO-UNDO.

    IF vhSocket:CONNECTED() = FALSE THEN 
    do:
        MESSAGE 'Not Connected' VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
        RETURN.
    END.
    lSucess = TRUE.

    DO WHILE vhSocket:GET-BYTES-AVAILABLE() > 0:

        SET-SIZE(mResponse) = vhSocket:GET-BYTES-AVAILABLE() + 1.
        SET-BYTE-ORDER(mResponse) = BIG-ENDIAN.
        vhSocket:READ(mResponse,1,1,vhSocket:GET-BYTES-AVAILABLE()).
        vcWebResp = vcWebResp + GET-STRING(mResponse,1).
    END.

    message vcWebResp view-as alert-box.       
END.
```

Resposne from webserver is:
*HTTP/1.1 400 BAD_REQUEST
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Close*

As You can see most of the code is taken from Progress docs and samples found in internet. I tried to modify my GET request in various ways but without luck. I also tried some differnet code, but I think that one is guides to proper solution. Expected result should be like on this site: [Geo location request](http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search.php?key=WLrMQcGao56Cb5m4ulmwZZDOegO3BkZn&format=xml&q=warszawa%20cha%C5%82ubi%C5%84skiego%208&addressdetails=1&limit=50). Some short documentation about this API can be found [HERE](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/open/nominatim-search/). 
This code will be running on UNIX server so I can't use .NET libraries.
Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
**PLEASE REMEMBER THAT HASH VALUE SHOWN IN KEY PARAMETER WILL BE DELETED VERY SOON! YOU SHOULD GENERATE YOUR OWN KEY FOR FREE AT business.mapquest.com .**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on a recent version of Progress OpenEdge (11.5+) you can use the OpenEdge.Net.pl (also available on Unix) to create the request, the following (running on Linux) could get you started:

https://abldojo.services.progress.com:443/#/?shareId=5b9064d6689ac207d7375047

```
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.RequestBuilder.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.ClientBuilder.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.IHttpRequest.
USING OpenEdge.Net.HTTP.IHttpResponse.
USING Progress.Json.ObjectModel.JsonArray.

define variable oRequest  as IHttpRequest no-undo.
define variable oResponse as IHttpResponse no-undo.
define variable oEntity   as Progress.Lang.Object no-undo.

oRequest    =   RequestBuilder
                    :Get(
                        "http://open.mapquestapi.com"
                        + "/nominatim/v1/search.php"
                        + "?key=WLrMQcGao56Cb5m4ulmwZZDOegO3BkZn"
                        + "&q=warszawa chałubińskiego 8"
                        + "&addressdetails=1"
                        + "&limit=50"
                        + "&format=json"
                    )
                    :Request
                    .
oResponse = ClientBuilder:Build():Client:Execute( oRequest ).

oEntity = oResponse:Entity.

def var lcc as longchar no-undo.

cast( oEntity, JsonArray ):Write( lcc, true ).

message string( lcc ).
```

The OpenEdge.Net.pl is also just using ABL code and sockets for communications.

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks a lot Stefan!
For others with the same problem: if You run some .p file from .sh script, please remember to add proper path to **OpenEdge.Net.pl** in Your PROPATH parameter, for example: `$DLC/tty/netlib/OpenEdge.Net.pl`.